# Bluetooth not enabled at startup on MacPro 3,1

Tags: bluetooth, mac-pro

I have an external BT controller with my MacPro 3,1. (I want it to support BT 4.0 which the built-in does not). A few months ago, somehow BT was no longer enabled at boot-time. How do I re-enable it? Mac OS 10.11.6.

The nvram settings are as follows:

```
EFIBluetoothDelay   %b8%0b
IONVRAM-FORCESYNCNOW-PROPERTY   boot-args
SystemAudioVolume   4
SystemAudioVolumeDB %f4
bluetoothActiveControllerInfo   %01%00%12%0a%01%00%00%00 =%00%1a}%daq%13
bluetoothHostControllerSwitchBehavior   always
bluetoothInternalControllerInfo %06%82%ac%05%00%00 ]%00#l%bd%e5_
boot-args   
boot-gamma  m%1e%00%00%d9V%00%00%00%83%08%00%b6%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%0d%00%01%01%e3%04%02%02%05%08%04%04)%0d%07%07%a1%13%0e%0e4 %18%18T/##%f8=00%a7M=='\NN%d7mrr%0b%90%9a%9a%90%b2%c9%c9%fb%d7%0d%00%01%01%e3%04%02%02%05%08%04%04)%0d%07%07%a1%13%0e%0e4 %18%18T/##%f8=00%a7M=='\NN%d7mrr%0b%90%9a%9a%90%b2%c9%c9%fb%d7%0d%00%01%01%e3%04%02%02%05%08%04%04)%0d%07%07%a1%13%0e%0e4 %18%18T/##%f8=00%a7M=='\NN%d7mrr%0b%90%9a%9a%90%b2%c9%c9%fb%d7
efi-boot-device <array><dict><key>IOMatch</key><dict><key>IOProviderClass</key><string>IOMedia</string><key>IOPropertyMatch</key><dict><key>UUID</key><string>EA7AF82F-7F7A-44D1-BEB0-35F3A2712898</string></dict></dict><key>BLLastBSDName</key><string>disk0s2</string></dict></array>%00
efi-boot-device-data    %02%01%0c%00%d0A%03%0a%00%00%00%00%01%01%06%00%02%1f%03%12%0a%00%01%00%00%00%00%00%04%01*%00%02%00%00%00(@%06%00%00%00%00%00%90`f%1d%00%00%00%00/%f8z%eaz%7f%d1D%be%b05%f3%a2q(%98%02%02%7f%ff%04%00
fmm-computer-name   Otheus%e2%80%99 Mac Pro
prev-lang:kbd   en:2
```

Comment: Have you tried booting into Safe Mode and then restarting your Mac Pro to see if it makes a difference? Also, can clarify the model of external BT controller you're using and how long it's been working fine for? Finally, did this problem coincide with anything else (e.g. software update, new hardware, etc)?

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If so, any update or extra info you can provide since my last comment?

Comment: sorry about delay. issue persists,. I cannot say when problem began. possibly after video card upgrade. typically after reboot, system would use builtin BT controller. Had to switch using  BT explorer, whicj often acts funny amd sometimes doesnt set pram correvtly.

Comment: What's your external BT controller? And, do you know _what_ the settings in PRAM should be? (you say BT explorer doesn't set it properly)

Answer (score 2):

Try a [PRAM reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) if you think NVRAM could be causing this. Other than that you can create a new admin user in System Preferences > Users & Groups and reboot into that. It won't fix the issue but if it doesn't happen you can be sure a setting or application in your profile is causing it. If it persists it could be NVRAM or even a software update.

Comment: is there a way to save existing pram settings? one problem i had was mac kept reverting to builtin BT after boot. this was changed via pram setting

Comment: I don't know the process for doing this manually but [here is a utility that can save and restore it for you](https://www.snbforums.com/threads/user-nvram-save-restore-utility-r24a.19521/).

Answer (score 2):

**Unplug the adapter and plug it back in.**

On my older Mac, in order to use macID, I had an LE dongle that has a blue indicator LED that would turn on (meaning it had power) but it would not broadcast BTLE until being removed and plugged back in.

Because of the design of macOS, it only recognizes the adapter after being removed and plugged back in for some unknown reason.

Unfortunately, after looking for solutions for a long time, this was the only one that worked for me.